# I want to return all the data in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL. I created a view as `orders` to get order data.

I want to return all the order information but it only returns the orders where the discount has been applied. My code is below.

```
CREATE VIEW orders 
AS SELECT order_number, staff_name, manufacturer, o.product_id, product_name, quantity, 
   o.delivery_address, discount_percentage, price*quantity AS Total
   FROM order_detail AS o INNER JOIN  delivery AS d ON d.delivery_number = o.delivery_number 
   INNER JOIN  staff AS s ON d.staff_id = s.staff_id
   INNER JOIN vehicle AS v ON s.staff_id = v.staff_id
   INNER JOIN product AS p ON o.product_id = p.product_id 
   INNER JOIN discount AS e ON e.discount_name = o.disocunt_name;
```

It gets an answer like

[image: this image]

While that answer is correct I want all the orders to return not just orders with discounts. Please Help.

Comment: Don't use image in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join`s.  Start with the table you want to keep all of -- `orders_detail`:

```
SELECT o.order_number, staff_name, manufacturer, o.product_id, product_name, quantity, 
       o.delivery_address, discount_percentage, price*quantity AS Total
FROM order_detail o LEFT JOIN
     delivery d
     ON d.delivery_number = o.delivery_number LEFT JOIN
     staff s
     ON d.staff_id = s.staff_id LEFT JOIN
     vehicle v
     ON s.staff_id = v.staff_id LEFT JOIN
     product p
     ON o.product_id = p.product_id LEFT JOIN
     discount e
     ON e.discount_name = o.discount_name;
```

Note:  You should qualify *all* column references.